# Angular 2RC - Warn user of unsaved changes when pressing back button on browser

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have put logic in CanDeactivate() to check for unsaved changes. This works fine if I try to naviagte to another page using RouterLink.
However, if I press back button on browser, Angular2 still triggers the CanDeactivate() method, but the locaion url got changed as well to the location.back url even I return false in CanDeactivate method.
(i.e. the web page stays the same, but url got changed).

Is there anyway to stop the url change?
(simiar to watching $locationChangeStart in Angular1)

Comment: The router provided with RC 1 was not fully completed and the team is currently working on a new, new router which will hopefully address this.

Comment: This problem still exists so until it is fixed I guess the only way at the moment is to use vanilla javascript to prevent this  issue!